# How to speed up logistic regression computation on large data sets in R

Tags: r, logistic-regression

All,

I'm working on an application that parallelizes the computation of a very large number of logistic regressions. I'm running an 8 core, Intel i7 processor on a mac mini w 16 GBs of RAM, but even with these decent system specs have found that computation times are painfully slow on data sets larger than ~100MBs. A compounding factor is that I programmed the algorithm to fully interact all categorical and continuous variables in the training frame, so a 1,000,000 x 8 matrix can very easily expand to, say, a 1,000,000 x 32 matrix.

Within R, so far I've tried coding up objective and loss functions that are passed to `optim` with `method = "L-BFGS-B"`, but in all my speed tests this basically broken even with the vanilla `glm` implementation.

I know that Python has some very good logistic regression tools, and that R -> Python, Python -> R integration is well supported. At the moment this is my go-to, although I haven't yet tested how much faster Python would be than R at logistic regression.

Other things I've thought about are trying to link R with Julia or F#, but writing good APIs to allow these languages to talk to each other is beyond my skill level.

Finally, I've checked out using Dirk Eddelbuettel's `Rcpp` package in conjunction with the `lbfgs` package to optimize my coefficients in C++. In addition to not knowing C++ (for now), I need a script that dynamically re-writes the C++ backend such that it matches the dimensions of the training data frame and the length of the parameter set passed to it on each iteration. Data dimensionality is dynamic in my algorithm, and I need an optimization program that accommodates this.

The program's workflow, currently all contained in R, is as follows:

(1) Import data

(2) Reformat data

(3) Apply logistic regression wrapper to data

(4) Use output to predict new data

Instead of re-writing the entire thing in a new language, I am looking for a way to make (3) a lot more efficient. I am constrained by CPU right now, not memory.

So to summarize:

- What are the best tools out there for doing fast, memory-efficient computation of logistic regression models? and
- Is it possible to smoothly integrate any of these tools into an R script file?
- How much more efficient is Python's logistic regression capability than R's?

Thanks,

Aaron

Comment: You should probably (=almost definitely) be using iteratively reweighted least-squares, with sparse model matrices if that makes sense for your application, rather than general-purpose optimization.  Start by checking out `glm.fit` and (1) stripping out anything you don't need and (2) adapting it to work with sparse matrices.  Also check out `fastLm` in the `RcppEigen` package.

Comment: Checking these out right now and making some comparisons, thank you, Ben.

Comment: @BenBolker: Have you played around with the `biglm` package at all? Looks like it's memory efficient--I'm wondering it it's also fast. Having read the documentation for glm.fit, the "Fitting Function" section appears to suggest that "glm.fit" can be swapped out for another optimization function in the namespace. Is that your understanding? Is there a function I could sub in that uses iteratively reweighted least squares?

Comment: `biglm` is likely to be *slower* than working entirely in memory. It's not intrinsically slow, but its main advantage is its ability to work out-of-memory.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried taking into account what you are doing to your memory management unit and your process scheduler?

1) If possible, chunk it down and forget about running a million threads in parallel. Just don't do it.
2) If you can't, find a lighter thread implementation and use third party libraries to do it. 
3) Change the number of times your scheduler pre-emptively switches from thread to thread. Or: 
   Turn off pre-emptive scheduling (Turn of interrupts) and manage your threads on your own.

Comment: thanks for chipping in. to make sure I understand you, you're saying that I should or shouldn't be running this job in parallel? I don't fully understand your answer here.

Comment: What I mean is, that if you are running a very large amount of parallel processes in memory, your OS tries to let them run with equal distribution over a period of time. If you are on a GPU and you have a load of cores to parallelize on it is fine, but if you work with max 4 cores, parallelization is just virtual and you have a lot of context switching do to your threads. If each thread additionally is fairly large compared to your Cache size, you system takes a lot of power out of the algorithms just because it needs to move data back and forth all the time.